# Need help to replace lines matching the key name in linux

Tags: text-processing, sed

Input file (has 2 lines with 2 key value pairs):

```
key1 = "x"
key2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Using this input file, I need to replace the key value pair on another file.

File1 (got 2 lines with 2 key value pairs):

```
key1 = "y"
key2 = ['p' , 'q', 'r']
```

Please let me know if there is any easy way in shell script to do this task.

Comment: I'm confused. What is the intended output?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to archive.
Assuming you want to patch a file `file.txt` containing text and your key value pairs like this

```
key1
key2
text
key1 = "original"
key2 = ['o' , 'r', 'i', 'g']
text
```

with a `patchfile.txt` only containing the key value pairs of the values you want to replace, like this

```
key1 = "patched"
key2 = ['p', 'a', 't', 'c', 'h']
```

without overwriting the text `key1`/`key2` that isn't a key value pair to get a `file.txt` like this

```
key1
key2
text
key1 = "patched"
key2 = ['p', 'a', 't', 'c', 'h']
text
```

by issuing a command like this

```bsh
patchmystuff.sh file.txt patchfile.txt
```

The content of `patchmystuff.sh` could look like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

original_file=$1
patch_file=$2

# loop from here:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash
while IFS="" read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
    printf 'patching %s\n' "$line"
    # (?<==) is the lookbehind for = to keep it
    # otherwise it will match key1/key2 in regular text
    search_string=$(echo "$line" | perl -ne 's/(?<==).*//g; print;')
    printf 'search string: "%s"\n' "$search_string"
    sed -i -e "s/$search_string.*/$line/g" "$original_file"
done < "$patch_file"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked fine for me!! 
I was able to update file using sed -i  option. So I dont have to create any temporary file.

Comment: You're right, that's a better option. I adjusted my answer.